# Newtonsoft Jsons Deserialize doesn't parse $ref objects

Tags: json, serialization, reference, json.net

I know it should work but it doesn't and i have no idea what the heck is wrong with that.
The Root["parameters"]-Dictionary is properly deserialized but the List of Parameter-References in root["paths"]["/alliances/"]["get"]["parameters"] is a bulk of null's.

I've shortened the Content. Origninal is [here](https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/swagger.json).
Switching from (my own) `SwaggerParameter.Deserializable` (which works fine in Root) to `JSchema` just changes from producing null's to throwing exception "Could not resolve schema reference '#/parameters/datasource'."

```
[TestClass()]
public class RootNode_Tests
{
    static string s_sContent = @"{
       ""parameters"":{
            ""X-User-Agent"":{
                ""description"":""Client identifier, takes precedence over User-Agent"",
                ""in"":""header"",
                ""name"":""X-User-Agent"",
                ""type"":""string""
            },
            ""datasource"":{
                ""default"":""tranquility"",
                ""description"":""The server name you would like data from"",
                ""enum"":[
                    ""tranquility"",
                    ""singularity""
                ],
                ""in"":""query"",
                ""name"":""datasource"",
                ""type"":""string""
            }
        },
        ""paths"":{
            ""/alliances/"":{
                ""get"":{
                    ""operationId"":""get_alliances"",
                    ""parameters"":[
                        {
                            ""$ref"":""#/parameters/datasource""
                        },
                        {
                            ""$ref"":""#/parameters/X-User-Agent""
                        }
                    ]}
                }
            }
        }";
    [TestMethod]
    public void Deserialize_Test()
    {

        TestRoot tr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestRoot>(s_sContent, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead, // shouldnt be neccessary
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
            TraceWriter = new DbgPrintTracer()
        });
    }
    public class DbgPrintTracer : ITraceWriter
    {
        public TraceLevel LevelFilter => TraceLevel.Verbose;
        public void Trace(TraceLevel level, string message, Exception ex) => Debug.Print($"{level}: {message} ({ex})");
    }
    public abstract class _TestBase
    {
        [JsonExtensionData]
        public Dictionary<string, object> m_dictAdditional { get; protected set; }
    }
    public class TestRoot : _TestBase
    {
        [JsonProperty("parameters")]
        //[JsonConverter(typeof(ParamCollectionConverter))]
        //public Dictionary<string,SwaggerParameter.Deserializable> m_dictParameters { get; protected set; } /* DESERIALIZES PROPERLY */
        public Dictionary<string, JSchema> m_dictParameters { get; protected set; }/* DESERIALIZES PROPERLY TOO */
        [JsonProperty("paths")]
        public Dictionary<string, Paths> m_dictPaths { get; protected set; }
    }
    public class Paths : Dictionary<string, Method>
    {
    }
    public class Method : _TestBase
    {
        [JsonProperty("parameters")]
        //  [JsonConverter(typeof(ParamCollectionConverter))]
        // public List<SwaggerParameter.Deserializable> m_lstParams { get; protected set; }    /* ONLY NULL's, NO EXEPTIONS */
        public List<JSchema> m_lstParams { get; protected set; } /* EXCEPTION: Couldnt resolve reference-Path. */
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the various settings of the serializer ( http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm ) ? You may want to activate some to handle the deserialization properlI can't help thaty.

A bet would be to active the ReferenceLoopHandling option and set it to 'Serialize'. I known some settings alter the json by adding special properties prefixed with '$'. Hope this help.

Comment: ya. no thats not the Problem. I had a look into the Source code. When a `$ref` appears, the `JsonSerializerInternalReader` tries to get the target from a Dictionary which is not initialized at that moment. Because there is a quick line (at several places) which makes the decision `if (id != null) AddReference(...);`. I'm now pretty sure that only `$id`'s can be `$ref`-Targets. Which doesnt correlate with the Swagger specification. damned. Seems to be a good day for learning how to write a custom Serializer *sigh*

Comment: ok now that I've identified the problem and know exactly what to search for I'll try out NSwag  [(https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag)](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag) and see whats happening.